# Объясните как 1 Класс с ArrayList может увеличивать число для нескольких View

Tags: java, android

Объясните как 1 Класс с ArrayList может увеличивать число для нескольких View
Там есть ArrayList. Но класс Модель создается 1 раз.

Почему тогда по нажатии на 3 кнопки для каждой число начинается с 0? 
Ведь 3 view должны использовать один ArrayList класса Model

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTXVJjf4vvs вот видео

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В конструкторе класса Model он сознает ArrayList c тремя элементами Integer:

`mList = new ArrayList<Integer>(3);`

Соответственно получается список с тремя элементами типа Integer каждый из которых по умолчанию равен нулю, тем самым при создании одного экземпляра класса Model, мы получаем список с тремя элементами внутри этого объекта. И с помощью индекса мы можем работать с каждым элементом по отдельности.

Comment: Спасибо понял..